# XlsxWriter set format on formula cells

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

After working on this for far to long.

How do I set the format of a cell that I either have written a formula to or will be writing a formula to?

Every other write_(), except write_formula(), includes a format parameter.

for example:

```
ws.write_number(1,1,quantity, fmt)
ws.write_number(1,2,price, fmt)
# ws.write_formula("C1","=A1*B1",fmt) <-- doesn't exists
ws.write_formula("C1","=A1*B1")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
extendedprice = (quantity*price)
ws.write_formula("C1", "=A1*B1", extendedprice, fmt)
```

I even figured out I can:

```
ws.write_number(1,1,quantity, fmt)
if (<price has an error>):
   ws.write_number(1,2,"n/a",fmt)
   ws.write_formula("C1", "=A1*B1", "n/a", fmt)
else:
   ws.write_number(1,2,price,fmt)
   ws.write_formula("C1", "=A1*B1", (quantity*price), fmt)
```

Answer (score 0):

A format can be applied to a formula with XlsxWriter in the same way as any other data type:

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

my_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'color': 'red'})

worksheet.write(0, 0, 'Hello', my_format)
worksheet.write(1, 0, 123,     my_format)
worksheet.write(2, 0, '=1+1',  my_format)

worksheet.write('A4', 'World', my_format)
worksheet.write('A5', 456,     my_format)
worksheet.write('A6', '=2+2',  my_format)

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]